# DocumentApp Script - Merge cell not working

Tags: javascript, merge, cell

```
 cell.appendTable([["Hello"],["Hello","I","J"]])
```

Outputs to:

```
|Hello|
|Hello|I    |J     |
```

I want to merge the first row.

Developed in scripts.google.com DocumentApp. - With Table And Cell Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Answer.
Merge Cell Functionality didn't supported by Google App Script yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you were expecting to have a merged cell that, like what you can do in a spreadsheet, that is not possible. Simply because that's not possible in Google Documents (at least not yet). Therefore the API cannot do this (it can only do things that are also possible manually).

Try **merge()** function : Merges the element with the preceding sibling of the same type.

> Only elements of the same ElementType may be merged. Any child
>   elements contained in the current element are moved to the preceding
>   sibling element.

The current element is removed from the document.

```
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Append two paragraphs to the document.
 var par1 = body.appendParagraph('Paragraph 1.');
 var par2 = body.appendParagraph('Paragraph 2.');

 // Merge the newly added paragraphs into a single paragraph.
 par2.merge();
```

**[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#merge%28%29)**